# Is there a word for a resource you retain even though you give it away?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if you give away or sell a book, you don't have it anymore. But if you give away or sell an e-book, you still retain the resource you have sold or given away.

You could think of this more abstract, too. For example, if you're an artist, you can "give away" your skills by making a drawing for someone and you have not lost your skills. However you can't get back the *time* it took to make the drawing, so your time is given away without you being able to retain it.

More poetically, love is something you can give away and you still have just as much to give.

Is there a word for this type of resource?

Comment: Your question is confusing process with things. I can't find a common element linking all three. It is too heterogeneous.

Comment: "bottomless" is a commonly used theme for this. It's handy because it's deployable over the entire gamut of uses you mention.

Comment: Well, up until that last part I was going to say you were *licensing* the resource.

Comment: @Lambie we have words for classes of things, and there are all manner of classifications (and, in fact, a good answer, with, I expect, exactly the word the OP is looking for)

Comment: @DanHall What is the common element in the three ideas? Is love a resource?? Without at least one common element, there cannot be any classification, classing or defining of them in a single category.

Comment: @Lambie the common element is exactly what the OP said -- a thing that you retain even if you give away. Love, for example, is an abstract thing that we speak of *having* or *owning* and *giving*.  And when you give it, you still have it. So it applies. I expect you can figure out how it applies to the other examples as well.

Comment: @DanHall Those three things do not have something in common that can be given away. The book/e-book thing is not a resource, love is not a resource. and the book/e-book thing does  not represent a source of something inexhaustible, as love might be. So, there is nothing, on the face of it, that links them. Which is why I do not understand the question. resources can be natural or metaphorical, but the examples are not coherent.

Comment: It's an abstract concept, @Lambie. The thing in common is that they can be given away and still used. They don't need to be the same type of thing, or involve the same type of giving. We say, "I can give you my notes", and mean that we will give them an electronic or physical copy of the same content. Some people give their ebooks to the entire world via bit-torrent. Like love, it's something you speak of as *having*, *giving*, and then still having. That's the thing that links them.

Comment: @DanHall What you retain with books is copyright.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79391/discussion-between-dan-hall-and-lambie).

Answer (score 5):

The term for the goods that are such that their use by one person does not diminish their availability to others is *nonrivalrous goods* or *nonrival goods*. Accounts of the contrast between rivalrous and nonrivalrous goods are available in numerous sources; a couple of the easily accessible ones are http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rival_good.asp and [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivalrous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivalrous). While this term captures precisely what the OP seems to be aiming at, it is a technical term, which will be readily understood only within certain theoretical contexts. The term *undepletable*, offered in another answer on this page, is less precise (it encompasses more than just nonrivalrous goods), but may be better suited for other contexts.

Incidentally, even though both *nonrivalrous goods* and *nonrival goods* can be found in the literature, the former is a better term, because what is relevant is not whether the goods themselves are rivals, but whether they generate rivalry among those who seek them.

Comment: I'm a wee bit disinclined to apply that to love ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about using the word 'Perennial" since it indicates something that is everlasting, used and yet retained.

Comment: Why is this any better or worse than any of the answers?

Comment: This is definitely not right. This means throughout the year... usually referring to plants that come back year after year. It can also be used to mean constant, but not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Perennial has metaphoric meanings as well.

Answer (score 2):

They seem to be called [virtual (or digital) products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_goods) by e-commerce software.

Answer (score 2):

"Share" is commonly used in this context; it may or may not indicate that your own share of whatever it is gets smaller.

Answer (score 2):

One might refer to these as "inexhaustible resources", denoting that they are infinite (and possibly self-replenishing); no matter how much you take away, there will always be more.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a word for this type of resource?

That would be an [**undepletable**](https://www.google.com/search?q=undepletable%20resources&num=100&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjisOGf--_bAhVLPawKHUMKCc4Q_AUIECgB&biw=1280&bih=588) resource, according to many references given in Google books, including:

*Uranium and Nuclear Energy: Proceedings of the ... International Symposium Held by the Uranium Institute*, c.1980

*Energy conservation: joint hearings before the Subcommittee on Energy and Power of the... and the Subcommittee on Housing and Community Development of the Committee on banking, Currency and Housing on title I of H.R.14205 and Title IV of Senate amendments to H.R.12169..., July 19-20, 1976*

*Handbook of alternative energy technology development and policy*, c.1983

*Gas World, Volume 180*, c.1975

*Solar Energy Fundamentals and Modeling Techniques: Atmosphere, Environment, Climate Change and Renewable Energy* by By Zekai Sen, c.2008